# How to convert String variable of POJO as Integer while converting to Json using ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have `Java` class which has `String` variable member

```
String sampleNumber="1234";
```

When I convert that `Pojo` to `JSON` using `ObjectMapper` I get:

```
{
  "sampleNumber":"1234"
}
```

But I need an integer type in `JSON` as follow

```
{
  "sampleNumber":1234
}
```

Can any one help me to get the expected results with using `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change property to `int`

You can change your property to `int`:

```
class Pojo {
    private int sampleNumber = 1234;

    // getters, setters
}
```

and you will get:

```
{
  "sampleNumber" : 1234
}
```

### Add new getter with right type

If you do not want to change property type to `int`/`Integer` you need to ignore `getter` which returns `String` and add new `getter` which will return `int`/`Integer`:

```
class Pojo {
    private String sampleNumber = "1234";

    public Integer getSampleNumber() {
        return Integer.parseInt(sampleNumber);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getSampleNumberString() {
        return sampleNumber;
    }

    public void setSampleNumber(String sampleNumber) {
        this.sampleNumber = sampleNumber;
    }
}
```

For above `POJO` you will get below `JSON`:

```
{
  "sampleNumber" : 1234
}
```

### Write custom serialiser which force `int`

You can write custom serialiser which tries to parse `String` and write it as `Number`:

```
class ForceIntSerializer extends StdScalarSerializer<Object> {

    public ForceIntSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            try {
                gen.writeNumber(Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                gen.writeString(value.toString());
            }
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            gen.writeNumber(((Integer) value));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as below:

```
class Pojo {
    private String sampleNumber = "1234";

    @JsonSerialize(using = ForceIntSerializer.class)
    public String getSampleNumber() {
        return sampleNumber;
    }
}
```

and you will get below `JSON`:

```
{
  "sampleNumber" : 1234
}
```